# Div is set to height 100% with scroll-y: hidden, BUT how do i get a child div to have scrollable?

Tags: html, css

Since this is purely HTML/CSS issue I did not tag angular as I reproduced it purely in HTML as a fiddle.

I have a div with a `height:100%` and `overflow-y: hidden` so the div maintains the viewport.

The issue though I noticed is that a div in there is populated by ngFor and scales off the page but it won't let me set `overflow-y: scroll` thinking it works.  It didn't though, so I'm a bit confused.

```
.banner { height: 100px; }
.content { height: calc(100% - 150px); }
.footer { height: 50px; }

<div class="banner"></div>
<div class="content">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

And then in the child component:

```
.content { overflow-y: hidden; }
.table { overflow-y: scroll; }

<div class="content">
  <div class="title">{{title}}</div>
  <div class="table" *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="headers"></ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't seem to get this working though.
Here is a sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uctxnads/

*Edit:* Please ensure you are using the current fiddle.

I am trying to get the content of the `div.table` to scroll, not `.contentB`. As I wanted to have the {{title}} to remain static if at all possible.

Comment: Replace this: .contentB { overflow-y: hidden; } to overflow-y: auto; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contentB class needs to have

```
    overflow-y: scroll;
```

This worked for me using your fiddle.

**Edit:**

For the scroll to work only within your table, you can create a parent div right before it with a class that adds a max-height and automatic scroll, like this:

```
    <div class="scrollable">
        <div class="table">
        <!-- contents of your table -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

And your scrollable class should have

```
        .scrollable {
           max-height: 50px; // You can set this as you wish
           overflow-y:auto;
        }
```

Working fiddle with this example: https://jsfiddle.net/jgztwmsk/

Comment: There is no need for the !important tag. I just noticed it worked without it

Comment: The important is not necessary!

Comment: @AlvaroCarvalho I am trying to get the `div.table` to scroll, not the entire contents of `.contentB`

Comment: @Fallenreaper added a parent div before your table with a class scrollable, set a max-height and overflow-y:auto, and it worked. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/jgztwmsk/

Comment: @Fallenreaper just edited my question. See if this works

Comment: @AlvaroCarvalho THIS IS IT!  Eureka!  Thank you very much.

Comment: Awesome @Fallenreaper! We all know the struggle that CSS can be. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS for `.contentB` to allow it to scroll:

```
.contentB {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fnrm4aLg/

And if you need the `.title` NOT to scroll, just move it up into the previous container, out of the current one: https://jsfiddle.net/p6xr39yv/

Comment: I am trying to get the content of `.table` to scroll, not necessarily `.contentB`.  Ill use this as a fallback, but i would like to keep content headers static on the page.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Please note the addition to my answer and the second fiddle.

Comment: The container itself is a Angular Component, so it is self contained as each module has its own title etc. Moving it to a parent in my eyes makes no sense.  The goal is that while the title of the module may change from page to page, I wanted to have the page define how the titling is done (If utilized at all)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the `calc` function, use a direct value.

You can use `overflow-y: auto;` on `.contentA`.

And on `.contentB` there's no need to change the overflow.

https://jsfiddle.net/ratyxpj7/

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.banner {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.contentA {
  height: 350px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}

/* This is the content of the inner component. */
.contentB {
  height: 100%;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.table > div {
  display: table-row;
}

.table div div {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="banner"></div>
  <div class="contentA">
    <div class="contentB">
      <div class="title">
        Title
      </div>
      <div class="table">
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
          <div>CellA</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This issue is that if you keep the content as non-calculated, I was thinking that the content window would not scale with screen resizing.  Maybe I am mistaken?  If you wish to change the question to remove the calc, you should give an alternative way to maintain the fluidity of the page, as this solution does not scale well if screen sizes change